# AJAX not submiting values to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send the contact form values to php using JQuery Ajax.but when i hit the submit button, i am able to receive the success message, but the values are not received in php and is not stored in database. what may be the issue?

here is what i have done

HTML

```
                <form name="contact-form" id="contact-me-form" method="POST">
                    <div class="med-col form-element">
                        <label for="uname">Name</label><br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-input" name="uname" id="uname" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="med-col form-element">
                        <label for="email">Email</label><br>
                        <input type="email" class="form-input" name="email" id="email" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="lg-col form-element">
                        <label for="msg">Message</label><br>
                        <textarea name="msg" id="msg" class="comment-box" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="med-col form-element">
                        <button class="contact-submit-button button button-black"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Send message</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="space30"></div>
                </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['uname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['msg'];

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "#userpass#";
    $dbname = "sample";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO contactdb (username, email, message) VALUES ($username,$email,$message)";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

AJAX

```
    var form = $("#contact-me-form")
    var formdata = form.serialize()
    $('.contact-submit-button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "contact-me.php",
          data: formdata,
          success: function(data) {
            alert("submitted successfully");
          }       
        });
        event.preventDefault();      
    })
```

Comment: seems like problem in your data use as `data:{value:formdata}`

Comment: Always the first thing to do in such a case: take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can read what the issue is. You _cannot_ develop php in a web environment without monitoring that file. That would be like flying in a narrow cave with eyes blind folded...

Comment: .. and you're missing semicolons  var form = $("#contact-me-form");
    var formdata = form.serialize();

Comment: @arkascha hey thanks, i found error in log. got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You need required changes as below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.contact-submit-button').click(function(){
        var form = $("#contact-me-form")
        var formdata = form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "contact-me.php",
          data: formdata,
          success: function(data) {
            alert("submitted successfully");
          }       
        });
        event.preventDefault();      
    }) 
})
</script>
```

Comment: Like this formdata will always be empty, since you serialize the code before the event. You'll need to do it inside the click event function.

Answer (score 0):

There are various issues with the javascript code, but the main problem is, that you serialize the data at the beginning before the click event, like this it will always be empty. Here is a corrected version:

```
var form = $("#contact-me-form");
// use submit event instead of click 
// to allow all kind of form submits
form.submit(function(event){
    // you'll need to pass the event as variable
    event.preventDefault();
    // and you need to serialize the data in the moment 
    // you need it, otherwise it will be empty
    var formdata = form.serialize()
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "contact-me.php",
      data: formdata,
      success: function(data) {
        alert("submitted successfully");
      }       
    });

})
```

And be sure to load everything when DOM is ready, otherwise your form selector could be empty. Either put the code at the end of the file or wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

Answer (score 0):

Use `form.serialize()` inside `click` function and add  `event.preventDefault();`  before `ajax` call

```
$('.contact-submit-button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $("#contact-me-form");
    var formdata = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "contact-me.php",
      data: formdata,
      success: function(data) {
        alert("submitted successfully");
      }       
    });

});
```